# Does MySQL have a date parser that can guess at input format?

Tags: mysql, datetime, time, datetime-format

I am working on a Python system that receives flat files and loads them into a MySQL database. The format of these files can change. Some will include date or datetime fields. I'd like to use MySQL's LOAD DATA command to load these files into their related tables. The problem is that I never know what format the dates are going to come to me in. For example, one data set may format a date value as *6/11/2018 17:53* while another may format it as *11/Jun/2018 17:53*.

Python provides a nice utility called dateutil.parser.parse that will take both of these and figure out that they both mean *June 11, 2018 5:53 pm*. Does MySQL have a similar function or must I know the input format and CAST the data from it in order to use it?

I'm trying to avoid having to write a Python program to read through the input files and adjust the dates on every record before I load it into the DB. (BTW, it's not the coding time but, rather, the execution time that worries me).

Thanks!

Comment: No, it doesn't. It has a default parser that just understands `YYYY-MM-DD`, and you can use `STR_TO_DATE()` to parse other formats that you specify explicitly. There's no heuristic parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does MySQL have a date parser that can guess at input format?

Unfortunately , it does not.

You are left with two choices.

1. Use string to store dates (which I highly don't recommend).
   You will have different date formats in the same column, which will be hard to convert to date using STR_TO_DATE() function.
2. Use Python utility called dateutil.parser.parse.

Even though you might have execution time issues I suggest using the Python utility.